# Check Current Version of Service Fabric SDK

Tags: azure-service-fabric

How can I determine which version of the Service Fabric SDK I have installed?

I've checked the Service Fabric Explorer and I couldn't find anything there.

I've check `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric` but I couldn't find it in there either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thankfully, the SF team made the SDK install like a regular Windows program, so it's in

`Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features`

Then search for "fabric". You should see the SDK and the runtime in there.

Comment: Normally I can see the version the way you described. But on VMs in our testing pool, it just shows "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK" with the date and size. Is there another way to confirm?

Comment: @dbconfession You normally wouldn't have the SDK on a SF node.  So it may be under "runtime" or some other name.  Or it may not be installed through the normal Windows install mechanism. You might have to find the runtime executables, then bring up properties, and look through the details tab info.